# retrieve data from ArrayList from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I create a model called Rating to insert all shopping cart elements into foodList

```
public class Rating {
    List<ShoppingCart> foodList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Rating(){
        //Empty
    }

    public Rating(List<ShoppingCart> foodList) {
        this.foodList = foodList;
    }
}
```

This is my one of the foodList element information inside the Rating Model:

```
"foodList" : [ {
        "img_url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/stomachhungry.appspot.com/o/all_uploaded_image%2FHalloween%20sushi.jpg?alt=media&token=1abda2a5-c232-4faa-a553-c3aa8c751fe4",
        "modify_date" : "2019/11/27 01:38:02",
        "product_name" : "Halloween sushi",
        "product_price" : "4.00",
        "quantity" : 1,
        "subtotal" : 4,
        "uploader_uid" : "cBzUNHceM2T47cr0zWX1tqgB2wA3",
        "usr_uid" : "2NUPkQuHFRS49ZHDZzEtWiErIiv1"
      }
```

Now, I want to print all foodList infomration from Rating Model. However, the model itself does not have any get function like getProduct_name(). I tried this code below:

```
String get_productname = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("rating").child("product_name").getDatabase();
```

The hard code is attempt to match if the database name called product_name.
I cannot get the product_name "Halloween sushi" from the model because all the data are in the ArrayList. Any help about the retrieve Arraylist information from the firebase model? thanks in advance

Comment: Add a snapshot of ur database

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot and indicate the exact data that you want to get.